# Question ban: Which questions to improve how

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, post-ban

Apparently I have a question ban on superuser.com. [This help page](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans) says that I should improve my existing questions in order to get out of the question ban.

Which of my questions have a chance of getting more upvotes by getting improved?

None of my questions have a score below zero. And I can't see my old deleted questions.

Answer (score 2):

#### None of my questions have a score below zero. And I can't see my old deleted questions.

You have asked 30 questions (15 are deleted).

Of those 15, 5 have a -ve score and count towards your question ban:

- -2 https://superuser.com/questions/1617414/opt-out-of-the-windows-update-that-will-deactivate-flash
- -1 https://superuser.com/questions/1566230/cache-file-names-or-contents-of-external-drive-propagate-changes-when-plugged-i
- -1 https://superuser.com/questions/1502598/delete-all-directories-that-are-empty-and-dont-have-in-the-name
- -2 https://superuser.com/questions/1487406/is-bluescreenview-the-perfect-tool-for-bsod
- -2 https://superuser.com/questions/1486573/community-for-resolving-bsod-issues

So that's 8 down votes. Unfortunately I don't see any way to improve those deleted questions.

To balance that you have 10 up votes on non-deleted questions.

Comment: @root - Having multiple questions that have received zero upvotes isn't a good thing.  I manually counted, and discovered you have 6 questions that have 0 votes, this doesn't count the 15 questions that were deleted.  By removing the questions you removed, you created a situation, where it will be next to impossible to get out of a question ban.  It should be pointed out that you were warned you were approaching the question ban threshold, you were warned, when you submitted your last question. I found at least one example of a question you asked, it was closed, then you simply asked it again.

Comment: @Ramhound Why was deleting bad? If I hadn't deleted them, they would have on average collected even more downvotes, which is worse, isn't it?

Comment: @Ramhound Regarding asking closed questions again: The message above a closed question says: "Your post has been associated with similar questions. If these questions don’t resolve your question, [ask a new one](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)."